# What does "new int * **[10]" do?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management, new-operator

I saw somewhere the following code and I am little bit confused.

```
int****            m_ppppCoder;
m_ppppCoder = new int ***[10];
```

Is that a 3 dimensional int array that allocated dynamically ? Can someone explain exactly, how it works ?

**Added after reading the comments:** The declaration above by itself, is not a complete 3d int array but the declaration structure with the 1st step of the array creation. According to this, with the following code below, You can create dynamically a 3d array. Is that correct ?

```
m_ppppCoder[0] = new int **[10];
m_ppppCoder[0][0] = new int *[10];
m_ppppCoder[0][0][0] = new int[10];
```

In this case, the actual data how are arranged (allocated) inside the memory ie sequentially ?

Comment: It indicates you should walk away from such code.

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: FWIW, the code creates an array of 10 pointers. The type of each of the pointers is `int***`. That **could** be the start of some multi-dimensional array, but at the moment it's just an array of pointers.

Comment: what does it do? It makes any sane programmer dizzy

Comment: It gives me a headache.

Comment: Yes, it could be a pointer to a 3d array of int type that uses 3 pointers to represent itself.  If you work with or write e.g C math libraries, you might find this pretty common.
That says, older generations of coders had a good time with C.

Comment: If you have 5 minutes to spare, I just recorded [a video answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZujDj979gYo) for you!

Comment: @fredoverflow Excellent explaination ! What app did you use for the visual representation ?

Comment: There should be a link in the video description (below the video and above the comments).

Comment: @TheUnknown  I've actually used code like that for interpolating 3D, evenly spaced structures. Once you set up the pointers to the appropriate places you can write expressions like `(v[-1][0][1]+v[1][0][-1])/2` However, I haven't done that in a very, very long time and when I did it was on embedded applications that had no cache. If was both efficient and the code was easily understood. It would be nuts and inefficient to write that these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is that a 3 dimensional int array that allocated dynamically ?

No.

> ```
> int****            m_ppppCoder
> ```

`m_ppppCoder` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

> ```
> m_ppppCoder = new int * **[10];
> ```

`m_ppppCoder` points to the first element of a dynamically allocated array of 10 pointers to a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

> Can someone explain exactly, how it works ?

Well, it's a pointer to an element of an array, so it doesn't do much of any work by itself. An example of usage:

```
int i = 42;                 // an integer i
int *ii = &i;               // ii points to i
int **iii = &ii;            // iii points to ii
m_ppppCoder[0] = &iii;      // the first element points to iii
int j = ****m_ppppCoder[0]; // the value of j is now 42
delete[] m_ppppCoder;       // never forget to delete dynamic memory
```

There is probably no good practical use for an `int****`.

---

> ```
> m_ppppCoder = new int ***[10];
> m_ppppCoder[0] = new int **[10];
> m_ppppCoder[0][0] = new int *[10];
> m_ppppCoder[0][0][0] = new int[10];
> ```
>
> In this case, the actual data how are arranged (allocated) inside the memory ie sequentially ?

Like this:

```
pointer to int***     p
                      |
an array of 10 int*** |->[0][1][2][3]...
                          |
an array of 10 int**      |->[0][1][2][3]...
                              |
an array of 10 int*           |-> [0][1][2][3]...
                                   |
an array of 10 int                 |-> [0][1][2][3]...
```

It's quite simple. You have allocated 4 arrays. Since they are separate allocations, each of those 4 arrays are separate from each other, somewhere in the free store.

Elements of an array themselves are consecutive in memory. Therefore each of the pointers (or integers in the case of the last one) are consecutive in the memory in relation to other elements of the same array.

Note that `m_ppppCoder[x]`, `m_ppppCoder[0][x]` and `m_ppppCoder[0][0][x]` are uninitialized pointers for all x in [1, 10).

Comment: @Borgleader The sentence also might be wrong. I'd appreciate a review, anyone :)

Comment: Thanx for your answer !